# PHP inserting an array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, insertion

I am a php newbie. I just need to know if its possible to insert an array inside another array like this? if you know a better way, please suggest.

```
<?php
$firstarray = array('name'=>'sample name','text'=>'sample text');

$secondarray = array(
       array('name'=>'sample name 2','text'=>'sample text 2'),
       array('name'=>'sample name 3','text'=>'sample text 3'),
       $firstarray,
       array('name'=>'sample name 4','text'=>'sample text 4')
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work when you try that code out?

Comment: Yes that is possible. Why dont you give it a try ?

Comment: You can add/insert an array into another array the same way you add/insert any other value into an array.

Comment: See also: http://www.php.net/array_merge

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: Should be fine. If you don't have a debugger to look at the resulting array, you can use the var_dump() function as a simple way to inspect the result.

Comment: If you don't have your machine at the moment but have access to the internet, search on the web with keywords like "online", "compiler", "PHP." You'll find many online compilers on which you can type what's on your mind and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_merge` php function to merging array,

check <kbd>**[demo CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/toJuJn)**</kbd>

```
<?php   
    $firstarray = array('name'=>'sample name','text'=>'sample text');       
    $secondarray =  array_merge( $firstarray, array(
               array('name'=>'sample name 2','text'=>'sample text 2'),
               array('name'=>'sample name 3','text'=>'sample text 3'),
               array('name'=>'sample name 4','text'=>'sample text 4')
               )
    );  
    print_r( $secondarray );    
?>
```

---

You can also create your own function to assign key and value.

check <kbd>**[demo codewiper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yhlVAT)**</kbd>

```
<?php
$firstarray = array('name'=>'sample name','text'=>'sample text');

$secondarray =  array_push_assoc( $firstarray, 'name','sample name 2');

function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
 $array[$key] = $value;
 return $array;
}

print_r( $secondarray );

?>
```